# Sentry with PHP: Scrub sensitive data in Exception message

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sentry

I am using Sentry in a Symfony project to report uncaught PHP exceptions.

Exceptions that are a result of a MySQL query contain the failed query in their message. Those queries may contain sensitive data, which I have to scrub before sending the payload to Sentry.

I am using the before_send hook to do so. The hook is calling, the data is scrubbing, but the unredacted sensitive data is still showing in Sentry.

Here is my hook:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Sentry;

use Sentry\Event;

class ScrubSentryEvent
{
    public function __invoke(Event $event, $event_hint): ?Event
    {
        if (!empty($exception = $event_hint->exception)) {
            if ($exception instanceof \Doctrine\DBAL\Exception) {
                $this->scrubSqlException($exception);
                $event->setMessage($exception->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return $event;
    }

    public function scrubSqlException(\Exception $exception)
    {
        $reflection_exception = new \ReflectionObject($exception);
        $reflection_message = $reflection_exception->getProperty('message');
        $reflection_message->setAccessible(true);

        $message = $exception->getMessage();

        $matches = [];
        preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $message, $matches);
        if (!empty($matches[1])) {
            foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
                if (!empty($match) && !is_numeric($match)) {
                    $message = str_replace($match, 'REDACTED', $message);
                }
            }
        }

        $reflection_message->setValue($exception, $message);
    }
}
```

And here is the result in Sentry. By calling `$event->setMessage()`, you can see that the redaction works fine (top). But the exception itself still shows the unredacted version (bottom).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was altering the original exception in the hook, but by then the SDK has already constructed the event's message. I needed to alter the `\Sentry\ExceptionDataBag` values in the hook instead of the original exception, by using `$event->getExceptions()` instead of `$event_hint->exception`.

This has the added benefit of not having to use reflections.

Here is the working code:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Sentry;

use Sentry\{Event, ExceptionDataBag};

class ScrubSentryEvent
{
    public function __invoke(Event $event, $event_hint): ?Event
    {
        if (!empty($exception = $event_hint->exception)) {
            if ($exception instanceof \Doctrine\DBAL\Exception) {
                foreach ($event->getExceptions() as $exception_data_bag) {
                    $this->scrubException($exception_data_bag);
                }
            }
        }

        return $event;
    }

    public function scrubException(ExceptionDataBag $exception): void
    {
        $message = $exception->getValue();

        $matches = [];
        preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $message, $matches);
        if (!empty($matches[1])) {
            foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
                if (!empty($match) && !is_numeric($match)) {
                    $message = str_replace($match, 'REDACTED', $message);
                }
            }
        }

        $exception->setValue($message);
    }
}
```